# Django ModuleNotFoundError, project cannot recognize my application

Tags: python, django, server, module

when i use 'python manage.py runserver'
ModuleNotFoundError is come..
project cannot recognize my application 'main'

i ask it to chatGPT and modify insert 'main' in settings.py

but project still cannot recognize 'main'

Comment: Can you show your folder structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using '*yourapp*.apps.*Yourapp*Config' in the INSTALLED_APPS

> If your app is called 'main' then use 'main.apps.MainConfig',

---

If you already tried this and it doesnt work, check if your app is in the right directory:

```
project
|- app
   |- migrations
      |- 0001_initial.py
      |- __init__.py
   |- __init__.py
   |- admin.py
   |- apps.py
   |- models.py
   |- tests.py
   |- views.py
|- project
   |- __init__.py
   |- asgi.py
   |- settings.py
   |- urls.py
   |- wsgi.py
|- manage.py
|- db.sqlite3
```

Comment: my app folder is in project folder...